# RDS SSL connection not working IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' has been resolved to the host name '80.pool90-69xxxxx, which resembles IPv4-address itself

Tags: mysql, ssl, rds

As per the question title, I am not able to connect to RDS using SSL as specified with in the IAM documentation in my company account.

[I've tested in my personal account following the same IAM documentation and it work as expected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html).

The weird thing is that when I try to connect via SSL I can see these in the mysql logs

> IP address '90.69.xxx.xxx' has been resolved to the host name 'xxx.pool90-69-xxx.dynamic.blahblah', which resembles IPv4-address itself

If I connect to RDS with username and password I am able to connect and for testing I've open all traffic to all world(I know it's a bad procedure but this is only for testing)

I don't know on what this could depend.
Does any of you got the same issue?
It's possible that the reverse DNS makes mysql crazy, or I am missing something?